# Expl3 equivalent to greater than

Tags: expl3, comparison

What is the `expl3` equivalent of the operation `>` (and also `<`). What I want is something similar to:

```
\ifnum\foo>\@ne 
<true code>
\else
<false code>
\fi
```

I know the `expl3` for `=`:

```
\tl_if_eq:nnTF { foo } {#1}
  { True code }
  { False code }
```

but I'm wondering what the code for `>` and `<` are. Also, is there some similar code for `≥` and `≤`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want `\int_compare...`  functions eg

```
\int_compare:nNnTF {3} > {4} {yes} {no}
```

Comment: I'm so slow ;-(

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know.

Comment: What about ``≥``? Do you just use the symbol or do you do something like ``>=``?

Comment: @Vebjorn use > and swap the order of arguments (as you would for `\ifnum`)

Comment: or use `\int_compare:nTF` which is slower but does allow `<=` and other forms.  see `texdoc interface3`